# jQuery: button click confirmation

Tags: jquery

I have the following html and jquery codes for deleting a member account with confirmation. But the code doesn't seem to work: even if I click "cancel" in the pop-up window, the request is still submitted and the account is deleted. How should I correct this? Thanks.

HTML:

```
<button class="member" href="/admin?arg1=deleteMember" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure？')">Delete member</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.member').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(url);
      return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you post some of the server side code?

Comment: just put `confirm` call inside the function instead of `onclick`

Comment: No server-side code is required here, this is a client-side issue.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.member').click(function() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      $('#content').load(url);
    }
  });
});
```

Then remove onclick attribute from the HTML element.

Comment: do i need the jquery file for this?

Comment: @NewbieCoder999 Yes, you'll need to include jQuery on whatever page you intend to use this code.

Comment: @NewbieCoder999: Technically, this could be done in plain JavaScript, without jQuery. But the original question uses jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

You've declared your events in two ways. One uses an inline event handler, and one uses JQuery. They don't react the same way to `return false`.

In a JQuery event handler, `return false` both stops the propagation of the event in its tracks *and* prevents the default behavior the browser would have applied. In a regular inline event handler, it just stops the default behavior. In the case of this button, there is no default behavior to speak of. It's just a button. So it happily returns false if you click "Cancel", then proceeds to run the JQuery event which is next.

To resolve this issue, it's probably easiest to put all the logic in one place—either JQuery or in the inline event, or have the inline event call a function where you perform all of the logic.

For example:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.member').click(function()
    {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (/delete/.test(href)) if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) return;
        $('#content').load(href);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Returning `false` in a click handler for a `button` (or an `input type="button"`) has no effect, because there is no default behaviour to stop, like with an `input type="submit"` button or a link.

Remove the `onclick` attribute in the tag, and call `confirm` in the jQuery click handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.member').click(function() {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure？')) {
      $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I figured it out by my own before looking at any of these valid answer. I am just going to throw mine for anyone to try:

**FIRST THE HTML**

**1st:** Suppose this is the button you are presenting to the user:

```
<button id="btn_to_check">Do Something</button>
```

**2nd:** Now only if the user clicks the button `#btn_to_check`you present them with a confirmation window with two buttons to confirm their intent (i.e. accept and go back):

```
<div id="btn_confirmation_window" style="display:none">
  <button id="accept" value="true">accept</button>
  <button id="go_back" value="false">go back</button>
</div>
```

**NOW THE JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#btn_to_check').on('click', function(){
  confirmationWindow();
});

function confirmationWindow(){
    $('#btn_confirmation_window').fadeIn(); //or show() or css('display','block')
    $('#btn_confirmation_window button').on('click', function(){
          var confirm= $(this).attr('value');
          if (confirm=='true') {   
                 //Code if true e.g. ajax
          } else if (confirm=='false'){
                //Code if false
          }
      }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: There are plugins like [jQuery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) or [jquery.confirm](http://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/), they come with all the bells and whistles. Such a manual approach obviously works, but you'd have to do all the styling yourself and you're basically writing a new confirmation script for each question (code duplication).

Answer (score 2):

I found this to be quite simple. It just uses bootstrap and jquery.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a[data-confirm]').click(function(ev) {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#modal').find('.modal-title').text($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
            $('#modal-btn-yes').attr('href', href);
            $('#modal').modal({show:true});
            return false;
        });
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a  href="controllers/my-delete.php?id=5" 
    class="btn btn-danger" 
    role="button" 
    style="width: 100%;"
    data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete?">Delete</a>

<div class="modal fade " id="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Are You Sure?</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        There is no way to undo this action
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a id="modal-btn-yes" class="btn btn-danger" >Yes</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```